# Preview method in Ruby on Rails - ActionController::ParameterMissing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, preview

I am trying to implement a preview functionality in Ruby o Rails 4; meaning the user can preview his post as it will be published, before actually submitting it.

The flow will be:

- New post-> fill out form -> click button "Preview"
- View as published (same format than *show* view) -> 2 buttons: *Post it!* or *Make Changes*; to save or go back respectively.

My methods are defined as follows:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description))
        if params[:previewButton] == "Preview"
          preview
          render :preview
        end 
  end

def preview
   if params[:createButton] == "Post it!"
     @post.save
   elseif params[:changeButton] == "Make Changes"
     create
     render :create
   end
end
```

The flow I am getting now is as follows:

- I fill out the form and click *Preview* button. It goes well to the preview view and shows the info I have just filled out, plus the 2 buttons (create and change) accordingly. So the info goes OK to the *render :preview* and the view is loaded correctly.
- Then, no matter what button I click next (*Post It!* or *Make Changes*), I get this error:

***ActionController::ParameterMissing in JobsController#Create* ; *param is missing or the value is empty: post***, highlighted in the first line of *create* method, *@post: Post.new(....*

Buttons seem to work correctly, but just in case I have implemented them as follows in the *html.erb* views:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |form| %>
<%= form.button :submit, name: "createButton", value: "Post it!"%>
<%= form.button :submit, name: "changeButton", value: "Make Changes"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you are not sending any data to controller from form

Comment: if @post has values then `form.hidden_field :title, {:value => @post.title}` `form.hidden_field :description, {:value => @post.description}`

Comment: Thanks! Your hint helped me to find what was going on.